# Binary cross entropy vs mse loss function when asymmetric payoffs

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, mse, keras, cross-entropy

I'm building a binary classifyer that has an unequal payoff given the following cass:

- $Y_{pred}=Y_{actual}= True$: payoff is +x*100
- $Y_{pred}$$\ne$$Y_{actual}= True$: payoff is -x*100
- $Y_{pred}$$\ne$$Y_{actual}= False$: payoff is -1
- $Y_{pred}=Y_{actual}= False$: payoff is +1

In other words, there are two possible courses of action: True for action 1 and False for action 2.

I'm looking at two approaches to implement it:

1. I could mse as loss function with two output neurons, assign the payoffs directly to $Y_{actual}$, with the neural network predicting the payoffs for each of the actions.

   - I assume I would then just look for which of the two neurons predicts a higher payoff and use liner function in the last activation layer. Correct?
2. I could create a custom loss function that will calculate the respective payoffs as described above and then use binary cross entropy on that?

Which of those two approaches would be preferred? Should they lead to the same result, giving a recommendation for each sample which action is preferable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use your "payoff" function as a loss for your network because it is not differentiable. Instead, you can use a differentiable function which has outputs close to your evaluation metric (payoff).

As you are predicting a binary variable, the way to go is the binomial cross-entropy. The loss function would look like:

$$\mathcal{L}(\mathbf y, \mathbf c, \mathbf t)=-\frac {1}{N}\sum_n 100c_n t_n\log y_n + (1-t_n)\log (1-y_n),$$

where $\mathbf y$ are the predictions, $\mathbf t$ are the targets and $\mathbf c$ are the individual costs for each sample. You can see it is giving the false negative predictions $100c_n$-times higher penalty than false positives.

It is possible that you will have to implement this loss yourself, but it should be quite easy.

Using MSE for classification [does not make much sense](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-main-reasons-not-to-use-MSE-as-a-cost-function-for-Logistic-Regression).

Comment: In my case each sample would need to have an individual weight. Also, cross entropy with weights only seems to offer a coefficient for positive cases - unclear to me what that means as I have basically 4 different payoffs that need to be weighted.

Comment: What is "x" in your "payoff"? The weight coefficient for each sample?

Comment: Yes that's correct. So I would need the samples weighted but also dependent on the outcome (if correctly matched or not).

Comment: Check the updated answer. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Ok that's great if this really works. In Keras binary cross entropy is calling tensorflow via `K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true), axis=-1)`. Any way I can rewrite this so I can make use of tensorflow's `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`?

Comment: I guess not, but you can use the tensorflow `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3d52b444a36c76ead0b129f215a9670cc6f4a1c6/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L104) and modify it for your purpose.

Comment: Ok so you suggest the term  `max(x, 0) - x * z + log(1 + exp(-abs(x)))` needs to be changed to `100*c*t*log(y) + (1-t)*log(1-y)`?

Comment: Yeah. Now that I am looking at the TF implementation, it is quite confusing why they require logit inputs and compute sigmoid over them... But the second formula should be just what you need.

Comment: I understand now how your function weights the false negatives and false positives. But what about the true positive and true negatives? Is there any way to weight them too in relation to each other? Any suggestions how I can handle that? Thanks for your great help so far!

Comment: These are correct predictions, therefore they don't belong into the loss expression: If they are predicted correctly, there will be no penalty. Also, note that this information is already inherently encoded: It is 100 times worse to mis-classify a negative sample than a positive one, that means it is 100 better to discover a true negative than a true positive.

Comment: I see what you mean, but in my case I don't really want to achieve the maximum accuracy in classification, but rather I want to maximize a payoff that is caused by a binary decision. That's why I think even the true decisions need additional weighting.

Comment: Have you considered using reinforcement learning? It might be the way to go for you.

Comment: I have thought about it but then rejected it as in my case each decision is not dependent on a previous state but is taken independently. I.e. the state is reset after each action. Not sure if my rejection is correct based on that reasoning.